# Carrierwave quality doesnt apply on recreate_versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, carrierwave, minimagick

I've encountered a problem concerning carrierwave quality settings.

To begin with, let me present some of the code (uploaders/second_image_uploader):

```
class SecondImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  def filename
    super.chomp(File.extname(super)) + '.png' unless super.nil?
  end

  version :full do
    process :quality => 85
  end

  # ...
end
```

and the quality process code (initializers/carrierwave.rb):

```
module CarrierWave
  module RMagick

    def quality(percentage)
      manipulate! do |img|
        img.write(current_path){ self.quality = percentage } unless img.quality == percentage
        img = yield(img) if block_given?
        img
      end
    end

  end
end
```

So, the problem:

When I upload a file on model create, everything works perfectly fine - carrierwave creates "full" version, compressed according to my parameters, creating image around 50kb - great!

Anyway, once I run `> some_model.second_image.recreate_versions!`, it recreates them, but without applying the quality param, increasing the size to sth around 500kb, which is kind of unacceptable.

I would be really grateful if any1 could help me to figure out what is wrong here.